# Enum with generic base class passed as contructor parameter

Tags: java, generics

I'm attempting to create an `enum` whose constructor accepts an object whose base class is a generic class.

I seem to be unable to fetch the underlying generic type from within the `enum` however, `Object` gets returned instead of `T`.

Is there a way to do this?

```
abstract public class Field<T> {
    abstract public T get();
}

public class IntegerField extends Field<Integer> {
    public Integer get() {
        return 5;
    }
}

public class StringField extends Field<String> {
    public String get() {
        return "5";
    }
}

public enum Fields {
    INTEGER (new IntegerField()),
    STRING  (new StringField());

    private final Field<?> field; // <<--- I can't have Field<T>, enum's can't be generic. :( 

    <T> Fields(Field<T> field) {
        this.field = field;
    }

    public <T> T get() {
        return field.get(); // <<--- Returns Object, not T
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you think an enum is preferable to this?

```
public final class Fields {
    public static final Field<Integer> INTEGER = new IntegerField();
    public static final Field<String> STRING = new StringField();

    //private ctor
}
```

or if you prefer

```
public final class Fields {
    public static Field<Integer> integerField() {
        return new IntegerField();
    }
    
    public static Field<String> stringField() {
        return new StringField();
    }

    //private ctor
}
```

Why would I want to call `Fields.INTEGER.get()` when I can just use `Fields.INTEGER`?

Comment: I originally started with the static field approach, but was trying to squeeze the enum paradigm in because each field is directly related, whereas a bunch of static fields is less cohesive....

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that enums can't be generically typed so even if you cast that get call (`(T) field.get()`) you won't have type safety because it will agree with any assignment (you could compile this successfully for instance: `boolean b = Fields.INTEGER.get()`).

Just use constants instead:

```
public final class Fields {
   public static final Field<Integer> INTEGER = new IntegerField();
   public static final Field<String> STRING = new StringField();
}
```

Comment: This is what I originally started with, but was hoping I could `enum`-ify things to make it more organized. It was worth a try. :P

Comment: @Ian I don't really see how it's "more organized". I think that's a distinction that exists more in your mind than it does in reality. If there is no reason why you would declare a field or parameter as the type `Fields` then it doesn't make sense to be an enum. In your case, there is no reason to do that, because you can already use the type `Field<?>` to express the same idea. If you want to limit the implementers of `Field` to some finite set, you can use [sealed classes](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/409) which went in to Java 17

Comment: An example could be if the enum represents a DB table and its columns. If I want to make a function that accepts fields only from that specific table and no other table, I'd need something like an enum. With the static member way, I need a common base class/interface.

In any case, I'll obviously have to go with the static member approach, but I still wish I could use an enum.